# How to call shell command for a single output when they run in a loop?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to use data of the shell command **top** in a python program, 
i am trying to do this with **subprocess** module,

but, the **top** command runs in a way that it opens in the terminal with a kind of its screen, which requires the keyboard interrupt to get back to normal terminal.

So when i run command from python shell for getting output of **top** from linux shell, the scrip just goes in infinite loop, it never ends.

So suggest some ways to get a proper output of such commands like **top**.

Comment: what are you trying to get from top?

Comment: Parsing the output of a command intended for interactive, human use is a bad idea. What is the information you are trying to get from `top`? There is almost certainly a better way to obtain it than using `top`.

Comment: i am trying to get cpu usage from top

Comment: There are lots of ways to get cpu usage without usng top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general case, you will have to **abort** the subprocess after you got the output you want.  You can typically do this by closing all connections to it, then upon its next output it will receive a SIGPIPE and typically terminate on its own.

In this particular case you can just call `top` **with option** `-n 1` to run just one iteration.  This will make it terminate after displaying one screen:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output([ 'top', '-n', '1' ])

print output
```

But beware!  This `output` will have a lot of terminal formatting sequences in it.  So parsing it might be a bit difficult.

If you want more output, you should also consider option `-b` (credit for this goes to @Klaus D.) which makes top not abort after reaching the current screen height.

Answer (score 2):

`man top` is very helpful.

You will find the `-b` argument for batch mode and `-n` for the number of iterations. Both together:

```
top -b -n 1
```

will give you the desired result.